# Spring Boot URL display after click on a link

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

My `Spring Boot` application is deployed in embedded `Tomcat` and it can be accessed through the following url `http://localhost:8080/displayResults`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "displayResults", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getResults(ModelMap model) {
    List<Bean> beanToDisplay = handler.getData();
    return new ModelAndView("Results", "beanToDisplay", beanToDisplay);
}
```

Now if I click on a link on the page displayed on above mentioned link, it performs some action. The link will take me to `http://localhost:8080/displayResultsChanged`. However I still display the same page for both the URLs it's just that it performs some calculations in the server.

Now my question is.. I don't want the URL to be displayed as `http://localhost:8080/displayResultsChanged` instead I still need `http://localhost:8080/displayResults` as the URL. How do I achieve that?

Comment: It sounds like you probably want to use AJAX...

Comment: @rmlan Thanks. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: There are literally dozens of articles on how to use AJAX with Spring Boot/MVC. Google around a bit and I'm sure you will find a simple example that suits you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use REST. If you want to stay on the same page and only make some calculations as you said. I can give you a tip or two.

Firstly annotate your controller with `@RestController`

After, leave one method that leads you to the page you wanted like : `displayResults` in your example.

Then you need to create a method that returns NOT `ModelAndView`  but `List<Bean>` in your case.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "displayResultsChanged ", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Bean> getChangedResults() {
   ...
}
```

Now it depends on the client side how to make the call and proces the data that the server returns. If you provide some client side examples maybe you will get more and better answers.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was able to accomplish this using Ajax